# List all sub-directories for a given HDFS path up to a certain depth using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have various Spark projects which write data in HDFS in just a few partitioned formats. 
Example:

**Format 1:**

```
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=x/dir4=y/second_id=4567
```

**Format 2:**

```
/tmp/myProject2/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=3212/second_id=9129
```

**Format 3:**

```
/tmp/myProject3/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=9912/dir3=x/second_id=1129
```

My question is given a base path which is  `/tmp/<myProject>/dir1/dir2/parquet` what would be the easiest way to dynamically build these paths up to **second_id**?

Note: I don't wish to use wildcards but instead want to get a list of all these paths dynamically up to `second_id` given any base path. I am not able to figure out a method that would be flexible enough to create a list of such paths up to `second_id` given any basepath as a parameter.

What I have tried so far is:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/"))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath))
```

This simply prints upto level 1:

```
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=x
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=a
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=c
```

Instead I want it to list all the files upto second_id, for example:

```
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=x/dir4=y/second_id=4567
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=a/dir4=z/second_id=1231
/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/dir3=c/dir4=k/second_id=4123
```

And similarly, for the other two formats it should list all files upto second_id. Is there a possible solution to this? I am pretty new to HDFS and Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a base path which is `/tmp/<myProject>/dir1/dir2/parquet` what would be the easiest way to dynamically build these paths up to `second_id`?

There is no such option in Hadoop FS API. For files, You can use [`listFiles`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-boolean-) method to list files recursively but you have no control over the max-depth.

For directories, you could do that using a custom recursive function like this :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def listDirectories(baseFolder: Path, depth: Integer = 0, maxDepth: Integer = -1): Seq[Path] = {
  val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  val ls = fs.listStatus(baseFolder)
  ls.filter(_.isDir).flatMap { s =>
    maxDepth match {
      case m if (m == -1 || depth < m) => listDirectories(s.getPath, depth + 1, maxDepth)
      case _ => Seq(s.getPath)

      }
    }
}
```

Using it for your example:

```
val baseFolder = new Path("/tmp/myProject1/dir1/dir2/parquet/first_id=1234/")

// listing all subDirectories up to second_id
val subDirectories = listDirectories(baseFolder, maxDepth=-1)

// listing all subDirectories up to dir4
val subDirectories = listDirectories(baseFolder, maxDepth=1)
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to list anything. I have imported all relevant packages, but this doesn't really display anything. Can you please check? @blackbishop

Comment: Looks like there is an issue for the second_id case with maxDepth=-1, if I specify maxDepth it works fine.